# What exactly is e4 and what is its meaning if I want to write a new eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4

I am interested in writing an eclipse plugin.

After reading various tutorials around the internet and working through some simple plugin examples, I am quite confused as to how you are supposed to use the new dependency injection/services style of programming I have read about in various places as one of the primary features of eclipse 4.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/FAQ#For_Adopters_.28Plug-In_Developers.29

The tutorials I've seen, and the eclipse wizard-generated plugins themselves, all use the "old" style of programming using extension points and referencing things using the singleton pattern.  Apparently, this style is supported using a compatibility layer.

The information on 3.x style plugin development seems perfectly reasonable and workable to me, but it sounds bad that it is only supported using a "compatibility layer."  Is this a style of programming that is going to be phased out/deprecated for Eclipse development?

Where can I find a guide on writing a plugin that uses the new, preferred style?  And why do the eclipse plugin wizards themselves not even use this style, if it has been the preferred development model since eclipse 4 was originally released?!  Everything I have found about writing eclipse 4 style programs focuses on standalone rcp "applications", not actual plugins to eclipse IDE.

Here are some tutorials I found which use what I understand to be the old style of plugin:
http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecplug/

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

Can someone explain to me clearly what the current status of the eclipse 4 programming model for plugin development is?  And if you could point me to some documentation of it that would be great as well.

Thanks!

Comment: It will be very long time before the compatibility layer goes as a huge amount of code depends on it. You can only really use e4 if you are developing a new RCP and don't need any of the existing 3.x style plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  Can you use extension points from old style plugins in e4?  If the answer to the above question is no, is that the reason why e4 development is not practical?  (because any practical work will depend on old-style plugins).

Comment: An e4 app can use extension points from core plugins which are not part of the compatibility layer. e4 development is perfectly practical for new apps that don't use compatibility layer plugins - I have several such apps. For a plugin to an existing RCP (such as Eclipse itself) the 3.x style is required.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If you put what you wrote in your comments in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be very long time before the compatibility layer goes as a huge amount of code depends on it.

You can only really use e4 if you are developing a new RCP and don't need any of the existing 3.x style plugins. e4 development is perfectly practical for new apps that don't use compatibility layer plugins - I have several such apps.

An e4 app can use extension points from core plugins which are not part of the compatibility layer. e4 applications make more use of direct injection and the application model which replace some of the old extension points.

For a plugin to an existing RCP (such as Eclipse itself) the 3.x style is required, although
Eclipse Luna provides some support for using e4 style views in a 3.x application.